# How to code on pine script to get previous 3 candle closing value and previous 3 candle rsi value on a screen mode

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I want a trading view screener which show  last 3 days candle closing value and last 3 days candle rsi value.

I just copy the rsi code and try to some changes to get it but I am not successful on it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

var table rsi_close = table.new(position.top_right, 2,2,color.aqua, color.black,2,color.red,2)
rsi = ta.rsi(close,14)

if barstate.islast
    table.cell(rsi_close,0,0,"Closing Prices")
    table.cell(rsi_close,0,1, str.tostring(close) + '\n' +  str.tostring(close[1]) +  '\n' + str.tostring(close[2]))
    table.cell(rsi_close,1,0,"RSI Prices")
    table.cell(rsi_close,1,1, str.tostring(rsi, "#.##") +  '\n' + str.tostring(rsi[1], "#.##") +  '\n' + str.tostring(rsi[2], "#.##"))
```